# Change device orientation using Appium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, appium

Is there a way to change orientation using e.g. Driver class like this:

```
private void SetDeviceOrientation(string mode)
        {
            switch (mode)
            {
                case ("Landscape"):
                    driver.Rotate(ScreenOrientation.Landscape);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
driver.Orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/orientation/set-orientation/) about setting the screenrotation suggests this should be possible. You should change the 'landscape' to uppercase. By researching the appium repository on github, it is mentioned in the ScreenOrientationExtension class as 'LANDSCAPE'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following and it supports in C# driver. http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/orientation/set-orientation/

```
driver.rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```